# WordPress Widget - JQuery Add Field Button - Fires Twice

Tags: jquery, wordpress, foreach, widget

I'm working on a WordPress widget that has a button that when pressed it adds a new field line. For some reason this code isn't working 100%. If I refresh the page and then press the button then it adds two fields the first time and then 3 fields the second time. However, if I click the save button first it works perfectly. Any ideas?

```
 public function form( $instance )
{
    $title = isset ( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : '';
    $title = esc_attr( $title );

    printf(
        '<p><label for="%1$s">%2$s</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="%3$s" id="%1$s" value="%4$s" class="widefat"></p>',
        $this->get_field_id( 'title' ),
        'Title',
        $this->get_field_name( 'title' ),
        $title
    );

    $fields = isset ( $instance['fields'] ) ? $instance['fields'] : array();
    $field_num = count( $fields );
    $fields[ $field_num ] = '';
    $fields_html = array();
    $fields_counter = 0;
    print_r($field_num);
    foreach ( $fields as $name => $value )
    {
        $fields_html[] = sprintf(
            '<input type="text" name="%1$s[%2$s]" value="%3$s" class="widefat feature%2$s">',
            $this->get_field_name( 'fields' ),
            $fields_counter,
            esc_attr( $value )
        );
        $fields_counter += 1;
        if ($fields_counter == $field_num) break;
    }


    print 'Fields<br />' . join( '<br />', $fields_html );
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var fieldname = <?php echo json_encode($this->get_field_name( 'fields' )) ?>;
        var fieldnum = <?php echo json_encode($fields_counter - 1) ?>;

        jQuery(function($) {
            var count = fieldnum;
            $('.addfeature').click(function() {
                $( ".feature"+count).after("<input type='text' name='"+fieldname+"["+(count+1) +"]' value='' class='widefat feature"+ (count+1) +"'>" );
                count++;

            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    echo '<input class="button addfeature" type="button" value="' . __( 'Add Feature', 'myvps' ) . '" id="addfeature" />';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem with widget that require js to manage their settings. My company does many custom widgets, and I have had this same problem many times. The problem is with the javascript and it's interaction with the entire page. If you have two if these widgets on the page, you immediately run into problems. FYI, if you add this widget to any sidebar, you already have two of the widget on the page, the one you just added to the sidebar, and one inside the 'pool' of widgets. Let me explain.

Lets say you add the widget to your primary sidebar. You click save and reload the page. Now you have this widget under your primary sidebar, and you click the add button and it fires twice. Why? The reason is because your javascript attached to ALL `$('.addfeature')` on the page, and it runs once for every copy of this widget on the page. You have one copy in the sidebar, AND you have one copy in your widget pool, which WordPress uses to clone new widgets from.

Generally speaking, the easiest solution is to make your javascript target a specific `.addfeature`, instead of all `.addfeature`. How? Like this:

```
// your code
...
print 'Fields<br />' . join( '<br />', $fields_html );
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fieldname = <?php echo json_encode($this->get_field_name( 'fields' )) ?>;
    var fieldnum = <?php echo json_encode($fields_counter - 1) ?>;

    jQuery(function($) {
        var count = fieldnum;
        // change this from simply '.addfeature' to a unique version of the name
        // which wordpress widget page will interpret for you, making it a unique
        // value for each copy of the widget, including the one in the widget pool
        $('.<?php echo $this->get_field_id('addfeature') ?>').click(function() {
            $( ".feature"+count).after("<input type='text' name='"+fieldname+"["+(count+1) +"]' value='' class='widefat feature"+ (count+1) +"'>" );
            count++;

        });
    });
</script>
<?php
// change this from simply 'addfeature' to a unique version of the name
// which wordpress widget page will interpret for you, making it a unique
// value for each copy of the widget, including the one in the widget pool
echo '<input class="button '.$this->get_field_id('addfeature').'" type="button" value="' . __( 'Add Feature', 'myvps' ) . '" id="addfeature" />';
```

My company has overcome this many, many times before. The `$this->get_field_id` function is available within any class that extends WP_Widget. It generates a unique id (and placeholder unique id) which the widget management page uses to uniquely identify widgets across multiple sidebars and the widget pool. This type of solution will help with almost all javascript problems on the widget management page. Hope this helps you and anyone else with a similar problem.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thank you for the explanation. I had no idea about the widget pool.

Comment: Yeah. I spent many an hour researching this the first time. Never again lol